# Compute the complex integral $\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

As one can easily see the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ has two poles $i$ and $-i$ which both lay on the circle with $R=1$ in the complex plane.

Does the residue theorem hold for such cases and thus $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{z^2+1}= 2 \pi i \left[ Res(f,i) + Res(f,-i) \right]?$$

Comment: The integral is not well-defined due to the singularities along the curve. To make sense of it (to get some kind of principal value) you need to specify a way to handle the singularities.

Comment: In order to define $\int _{\gamma}f(z)dz$,  function $f$ should be defined on the curve $\gamma$. Your "integral" is a generalized version of the above, which you should define from the start somehow (after that, you may about its properties).

Comment: You are trying to obtain the value of something that is not defined. Ignore the answers below that claim the result to be $0$. That integral simply does not exist (i.e. it cannot be defined as a mathematical object in the usual framework of complex analysis, unless you come up with some concept of integral with singularities). People "calculating" your integral show the dangers of incomplete, amateurish mathematical instruction.

Comment: What is wrong with using Laurent Series??

Comment: @AlexM. Principal value integrals are not very unusual in applications of the residue theorem. It's fairly run-of-the-mill to deal with cases like this one.

Comment: The short answer: The residue theorem holds with a small modification, $$\operatorname{v.p.} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{dz}{z^2+1} = \pi i \bigl(\operatorname{Res}(f,i) + \operatorname{Res}(f,-i)\bigr).$$ Since the contour passes through the poles and has an interior angle of $\pi$ at the poles, the residues must be multiplied with $\pi i$ instead of $2\pi i$ for the principal value integral.

Comment: But it should also be clearly stated, that *without* modification the integral is *not defined*. In order to apply the residue theorem the function has to be *holomorphic*, resp. analytic  in an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which contains the curve $|z|=1$. The singularities violate this requirement, since $f$ is not defined at $z=i$ and $z=-i$.